# F# 2.0 namespace warning

Tags: f#, namespaces

I just installed the latest version of F#, and opened an old solution to see what it would tell me.

It's a multi-file solution, where the first file includes some 'extension functions' on the List module:

```
module List = 
    ///Given list of 'rows', returns list of 'columns' 
    let rec transpose lst =
        match lst with
        | (_::_)::_ -> List.map List.hd lst :: transpose (List.map List.tl lst)
        | _         -> []
```

The compiler no longer likes this, and says:

> Files in libraries or multiple-file applications must begin with a namespace or module declaration, e.g. 'namespace SomeNamespace.SubNamespace' or 'module SomeNamespace.SomeModule'

But if I do this:

```
module Foo.List =
```

It says:

> A module abbreviation must be a simple name, not a path

What am I missing here? And what is the solution for this 'special' case where I'm extending a module that comes from elsewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the namespace explicit:

```
namespace Microsoft.FSharp.Collections

module List =  
    ///Given list of 'rows', returns list of 'columns'  
    let rec transpose lst = 
        match lst with 
        | (_::_)::_ -> List.map List.head lst :: transpose (List.map List.tail lst) 
        | _         -> []
```

Note that `List.hd` and `List.tl` have been renamed to `List.head` and `List.tail`.

Comment: hd -> head and tl -> tail? Don't these people care about code golf? :)

Comment: The other half of the answer, which is very confusing, is that if you have no namespace, and just a module, you mustn't put an = after the module declaration. But if you do have a namespace, you need an =